# regex fails when trying to match whole word

Tags: grep, regular-expression, python, search, pattern-matching

Here is my test file test.txt

```
hello

user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/* /app/tomcat/tomcat*/webapps/*, /usr/bin/rm -rf /app/tomcat/tomcat*/webapps/*,/bin/rm -rf /app/tomcat/tomcat*/webapps/**.sh , /bin/kill -3 *
```

I'm able to successfully find for the desired line using the below regex

```
grep -P '(^[^#;]ser1.*ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD.*\/app\/tomcat.*$)' test.txt
```

However, when I give complete word `user1` instead of `ser1` the regex does not match

Failing regex below reason; it does not match:

```
grep -P '(^[^#;]user1.*ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD.*\/app\/tomcat.*$)' test.txt
```

I want to provide `user1` in the regex to match the line.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: note that the `user1.*ALL=` part would also match `user123 ALL=...` etc. because the `.*` matches anything, not just whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to achieve two things explicitly which however imply each other:

- the line should start with `user1`
- the line should not start with a comment sign (`#` or `;`)

However, your second regular expression states "the line shall start with any character that is not `#` or `;`, and then contain `user1`. So, `grep` expects that there is a character before `user1`. This is no problem in the first regular expression where you demand "any character that is not `#` or `;` followed by `ser1`", as `user1` does start with a character that is not `#` or `;`.

If you are sure that the line begins with `user1`, you can simply use

```
grep -P '^user1 etc.'
```

or, if there might be spaces,

```
grep -P '^ *user1 etc.'
```

Answer (score 3):

You are anchoring your regex to the beginning of the line:

```
^[^#;]ser1
```

That means "match lines that start with any character other than `#` or `;`, and then the sting `ser1`. So, the `[^#;]` is matching the `u` of `user1`. If you want to give the whole word, you need to look for lines starting with `user1` directly:

```
^user1
```

Alternatively, allow for 0 occurrences of the `[^#;]` pattern:

```
^[^#;]*ser1
```

So, your full command could be like this:

```
grep -P '(^user1.*ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD.*\/app\/tomcat.*$)' test.txt
```

or

```
grep -P '(^[^#;]*user1.*ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD.*\/app\/tomcat.*$)' test.txt
```

However, this seems very, very complicated. All you really need is:

```
grep -P '^[^#;]*user1'
```

in this example.

Comment: I guess since we're already using `-P` here, another option would be negative lookbehind `^(?<![#%;])user1`

Comment: but `^[^#;]*user1` would also match `xxuser1`, etc.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, but maybe that's what the OP wants. How can we know? That is what the original command was doing, after all. I supposed we could use `^[^#;]?` instead, but we'd need to know what the objective is and the question doesn't explain.

Comment: @terdon, weell. They did mention "giving the complete word 'user1'", so it seemed to me they wanted to find a particular user name, which also seems kinda logical in this use case. The original doesn't match anything ending with the given string anyway, just those with one letter in front (i.e. `xuser1`, but not `xxuser1`). I got the impression they used `[^#;]` trying to mean "no # or ; here", missing that it really means "something here that's not # or ;". That seems a not uncommon misunderstanding, but of course I am guessing a bit on what they really meant.